# Amazon EMR Pyspark Module not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I created an Amazon EMR cluster with Spark already on it. When I run pyspark from the terminal it goes into the pyspark terminal when I ssh into my cluster.

I uploaded a file using scp, and when I try to run it with python FileName.py, I get an import error:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

I add the following lines to `~/.bashrc` for emr 4.3:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.XXX-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```

Here `py4j-0.XXX-src.zip` is the py4j file in your spark python library folder.  Search `/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/` to find the exact version and replace the `XXX` with that version number.

Run `source ~/.bashrc` and you should be good.

Comment: `py4j-0.10.7-src.zip` for emr 5.16

Comment: This didn't work for me on a Jupyter notebook. Still getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'`

Comment: This is a hacky but effective way to be able to use spyder remote kernels plus spark on an EMR cluster.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to add the pyspark files to the path. I typically use a function like the following.

```
def configure_spark(spark_home=None, pyspark_python=None):
    spark_home = spark_home or "/path/to/default/spark/home"
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_home

    # Add the PySpark directories to the Python path:
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python'))
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python', 'pyspark'))
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python', 'build'))

    # If PySpark isn't specified, use currently running Python binary:
    pyspark_python = pyspark_python or sys.executable
    os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = pyspark_python
```

Then, you can call the function before importing pyspark:

```
configure_spark('/path/to/spark/home')
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

Spark home on an EMR node should be something like `/home/hadoop/spark`. See https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/4926593393724923 for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark): Install via shell using `pip install findspark`.

Sample code:

```
# Import package(s).
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
```