# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently installed pyspark on Linux and get the error when importing pyspark:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

Pyspark is in my 'pip list'

I addded the following lines to my .bashrc:

```
export SPARK_HOME=~/Spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

If I type pyspark from the terminal, it work properly:

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/
Using Python version 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020 13:03:44)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

In the terminal I can do all my coding, it just doesn't load import pyspark from a python script. It looks like my environment variables are okay.

I then typed:

```
import findspark
print(findspark.init())
```

And it says;
ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation)

Comment: how do you run your script? try use python with version: `python3.7 script.py`

Comment: your solution indeeds works. Good to know how I can run it succesfully, but still want to know how I can do it in my interpreter (I use Thonny)

Comment: try to do this https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-associate-a-python-3-virtual-environment-with-thonny/

Comment: What is the output when you type `echo $SPARK_HOME` in your terminal?

Comment: Does this question helps: [How to Setup SPARK_HOME variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613651/how-to-setup-spark-home-variable)

Comment: Also don't forget to set `JAVA_HOME` too.

Comment: echo gives me: /home/pi/Spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7; the virtual environment was indeed already configured in Thonny

Comment: what is the python script name from which you are tryin to run.. it should not be pyspark

Comment: Name is test.py, I dont want to develop anything in JAVA. I have installed and run pyspark succesfully with windows on another computer and have not used JAVA_HOME there. I doubt whether JAVA will have to do anything with it, becuase I can run the script from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

check your environment variable set properly or not by using

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
cd $SPARK_HOME/bin
```

or provide complete path in script

```py
import findspark
print(findspark.init('~/Spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/'))
```

Comment: This did not work. Pyspark is configured correctly, since it is running from the shell. It just doesnt run from a python script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when running a pyspark code on a Mac.

It worked when I addded the following line to my .bashrc:

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name job_name --master local --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true pyspark-shell"
```

Or, when I added in my python code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = """--name job_name --master local --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true pyspark-shell"""
```